# Edit page slug after save, cause 404 by linked pages

Tags: permalinks, hooks, 404-error, slug

I have two page

1. *bar* page at url: http://www.example.com/bar/
2. *foo* page at url: http://www.example.com/foo/

*bar* page link to *foo* page in content, eg.:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/foo/">foo</a>
```

now, i edit the slug for *foo* page, eg.:

```
http://www.example.com/baz-foo/
```

now the link in *bar* page is wrong and cause a 404 error.

My idea is: when a user change the slug of a page, i replace the old slug with the new in the database, eg. (pseudocode):

```
// Replace in every posts the old slug with the new
add_action('update_slug', 'my_update_slug', 10, 2);
function my_update_slug($old_slug, $new_slug){
    $sql = "UPDATE wordpress.wp_posts 
            SET post_content = replace(post_content, '$old_slug', '$new_slug');";
    // ...
}
```

a bit of question...

1. Wordpress has some hook for catch the update of slug?
2. Exists other way to make this?

Sorry for my (poor/beginner's/basic) English.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If user edits the slug and save the page, the slug is already saved in database (unless the user is a contributor; only authors, editors and admins can edit slugs). What you should update are the links pointed to the old slug or redirect the requests with the old slug to the new one (usually WordPress takes care of this redirection, it is not working for you?).

Comment: @cybmeta I would update the old url saved in the other post content; WordPress takes care of this redirection?! not work for me...

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. WordPress takes care of the redirection only for posts by default, not for pages.

Comment: One way to do this is have WP insert the page ID instead of the slug when adding links. See [How can I store page ID in a post instead of other selected permalink](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156032/how-can-i-store-page-id-in-a-post-instead-of-other-selected-permalink)? That way no matter what the slug changes to the links won't break.